# macOS application like Photos.app on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow, nsviewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I'm trying to create a macOS app like Photos.app. The `NSWindowController` has a toolbar with a segmented control. When you tap on the segmented control, it changes out the the `NSViewController` within the `NSWindowController`.

[image: Example of Apple Photos.app.]

What I have so far is an `NSWindowController` with an `NSViewController`. I have subclassed `NSWindowController` where I have the method that gets called whenever the user taps on the segmented control.

Essentially, whatever segment is clicked, it will instantiate the view controller that is needed and set it to the `NSWindowController`'s `contentViewController` property.

[image]

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Also, the `NSWindowController`, I am thinking, should have properties for each of the `NSViewController`s it can switch to that get lazy loaded (loaded when the user taps them and they get held around to be re-used to prevent re-initializing).

Code:

```
import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController
{
    var secondaryViewController:NSViewController?

    override func windowDidLoad()
    {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    }

    @IBAction func segmentedControlDidChange(_ sender: NSSegmentedControl)
    {
        print("Index: \(sender.selectedSegment)")

        if sender.selectedSegment == 3 {
            if secondaryViewController == nil {
                let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "SecondaryViewController") as! NSViewController
                secondaryViewController = viewController
            }

            self.window?.contentViewController = self.secondaryViewController
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to macOS development, however, I've been doing iOS for quite some time. If there is a better way, I'd like to know about it. Thanks!!!

Comment: You could also consider using NSTabViewController.

Comment: @jtbandes This is true but I'm trying to keep the consistent look of other macOS applications by Apple such as Photos, Notes, and Maps. I need the segmented control to remain in the toolbar alongside other things like search bars and buttons. Thank you for your input!

Comment: NSTabViewController can be used without visible tabs, just to handle the switching between content VCs.

Answer (score 2):

to move the tab/segmented-control to the titlebar, you need:

1. add toolbar to window, and add the controls to the toolbar,
2. hide title:

   ```
   class TopLevelWindowController: NSWindowController {

     override func windowDidLoad() {
       super.windowDidLoad()

       if let window = window {

           // reminder like style
           // window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
           window.titleVisibility = .hidden
           // window.styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. now, toolbar will be merged into the top bar position.